# In how many ways can 10 people be split into five groups of 2?

Tags: combinatorics

My reasoning for this is as follows: you first pick two from 10, then two from 8, et cetera until nobody is left. The order doesn't matter, so you also divide by the number of permutations of the 5 groups:

$$
\frac{C_2^{10} \cdot C_2^8 \cdot C_2^6 \cdot C_2^4 \cdot C_2^2}{5!}
$$

I'm not at all confident with combinatorics though; is this formula correct?

Comment: Another way to look at it is to first select the first member of the 2-man team for each team in $\binom{10}{5}$ ways and then then multiplying by $5!$ gives all the possible combinations of the 2-man team (permuting remaining 5 members for the second position. Also, since team (A,B) is same as (B,A), we divide by $(2!)^5$. So, the answer is $$\dfrac{\binom{10}5}{(2!)^5}\times 5!=\frac{10!\times 5!}{5!\times 5!\times 2^5}=\frac{6\times 7\times\cdots 10}{2^5}=\frac{30240}{2^5}=945$$ which agrees with your result.

Comment: Your result is right.

Comment: Biswas:  I believe you are incorrect because you could have chosen person X1 as the first person in a specific group and then Y1 to be his partner OR you could have chosen Y1 to be the first person in a specific group and then X1 to be his partner.  But these are the same final group.  You've overcounted.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, yes I noticed that just now. I've fixed the error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your answer is correct, but it may help also to see an answer that avoids "division by symmetry" arguments.  Another way of expressing the answer is $9!!=9\cdot 7\cdot 5\cdot 3\cdot 1=945$ using [double-factorial notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial).

To arrive at this answer recognize that for our ten people, there must be some way of distinguishing them and therefore ordering them.  I will continue this explanation as though we ordered them by height.

Approach by multiplication principle:

- Pick who the person to be partnered with the shortest person is.  (*9 options*)  Remove both the shortest person and his chosen partner from the available people.
- Pick who the person to be partnered with the shortest remaining person is.  (*7 options*)  Remove both the current shortest person and his chosen partner from the available people.
- Repeat this process until all people have received partners.

This gives $9\cdot 7\cdot 5\cdot 3\cdot 1=945$ possibilities.